# Functional test of RESTful Basic Auth fails, Postman succeeds

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

Functional test of a FOSRestBundle app fails with a 401 code while Postman, with identical credentials, passes.  Test db is sqlite, prod db is MySQL. Stored passwords are identical.

The test:

```
public function testBasicAuth() {
    $client = static::createClient([], ['PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'admin',
        'PHP_AUTH_PW' => '123Abc',]);

    $crawler = $client->request(
            'GET', '/basic/get_user/bborko@bogus.info'
    );
    $this->assertSame(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

The failure:

> Failed asserting that 401 is identical to 200.

The controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/get_user/{email}", name="basic_get_user")
 * 
 * @return View
 */
public function getUserAction($email) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $data = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member')->findBy(['email' => $email]);

    if (!$data) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find user entity');
    }
    $view = $this->view($data, 200)
            ->setTemplate("AppBundle:Users:getUsers.html.twig")
            ->setTemplateVar('user')
    ;

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

#### Edit:

Note: The app also has an API/API-key route that tests successfully.
security.yml:

```
...
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        api_key_user_provider:
            id: api_key_user_provider
...
    firewalls:
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: apikey_authenticator
            provider: api_key_user_provider
        basic:
            pattern: ^/basic/
            http_basic: 
                provider: fos_userbundle
            anonymous:    false
...
    access_control:
...
        - { path: ^/api/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/basic/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Postman:
[image: Postman confi]

Comment: Show your security configs. Crawler is running in test environment, while requests from postman are being processed in prod or dev environments.

Comment: Good point.  `security.yml` added in edit.

Comment: Assuming the config is not overwritten, try to swap db settings for dev/prod and test configs to confirm it is not data issue.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for setting me on the right track.  The error was in my test fixture - I hadn't included necessary properties for the admin user. I'll happily accept your suggestion as an answer.  Plus - since the RESTful app is really just a test fixture itself it's best for its database to be in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch in postman in tab "Headers" you'll should see the header "Authorization: {some token}". It is send for authorization user by Basic Auth. You can get this toke by function `base64_encode("username:password")` (colon is require). Try authorize your user in test by this token

Comment: While this is an interesting idea it also failed.  I'll continue to try switching db's although that is a big rabbit hole for now.